# Grails with MySQL throwing error

Tags: mysql, grails

I am trying to use MySQL with Grails.. as per the documentation on grails i have downloaded the MySQL connector and placed the jar file at the path grails-app/lib.

But while running the application i am getting a lot of errors. Some of them are as follows which I think if solved can solve the rest of them.

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.3
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 236 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
C:\xp\sst workspace\racetrack\grails-app\lib\src\com\mysql\jdbc\integration\c3p0\MysqlConnectionTester.java:31: error: package com.mchange.v2.c3p0 does not exist
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0ProxyConnection;
                          ^
C:\xp\sst workspace\racetrack\grails-app\lib\src\com\mysql\jdbc\integration\c3p0\MysqlConnectionTester.java:32: error: package com.mchange.v2.c3p0 does not exist
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.QueryConnectionTester;
                          ^
C:\xp\sst workspace\racetrack\grails-app\lib\src\com\mysql\jdbc\integration\c3p0\MysqlConnectionTester.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
public final class MysqlConnectionTester implements QueryConnectionTester {
                                                    ^
  symbol: class QueryConnectionTester
C:\xp\sst workspace\racetrack\grails-app\lib\src\com\mysql\jdbc\integration\jboss\ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter.java:28: error: package org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor does not exist
import org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter;
                                             ^
.......... etc
44 errors
2 warnings
1 error
```

Please help me solving this problem...

Answer (score 0):

1. Where does the documentation say `grails-app/lib`? I believe it should just be `lib/`
2. Are you sure you put the binary jar in there, and not some sort of source code jar?

You should remove whatever you did inside `grails-app`, then simply uncomment the line:

```
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
```

in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response. I read that in the getting started book for grails to add the jar in that folder. ALthough I followed the steps mentioned by you. Now, I am getting some other errors. Error 2012-05-22 19:27:26,791 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' wh

Comment: @ShubhamMittal Can you try running `grails clean`?  Whatever you did the first time might still be hanging around and polluting the classpath

Comment: yes i tried that also .. i saw this problem already present on stackoverflow.. tried grails clean.. but it didnt worked.

Comment: Try creating a new grails app.  Edit `BuildConfig.groovy` as above, then `grails run-app`.  I assume that works?  If so, I don't know what you've done, but it looks like copying the wrong thing into the wrong place has broken something :-(

Comment: Hey! It worked in a new application.. although the app is working and data is stored in mysql, it throws some runtime exceptions..   Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
| Error  at com.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:91)
| Error  at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188) and many more like that.. i am trying to figure out why it is doing so.. thanks a lot for your help .. :)